# Calculated Columns - calculating due date from 2 different columns

Tags: 2007, 2003

I have a list with mandatory training. One training course has to be completed, but is a one off course, so not calculation for a due date to retrain. The other course has to be completed 2 years after the one of course and then every 2 years thereafter. 
So I have the one off course A complete date column and the continuation course B completed date column, a due date for continuation course column and an indicator column.

What I want the due date column to work out is, if the course A completed is empty leave blank, if its got a date in calculate 2 years from that date, and if the course B completed column is empty leave blank or if it has a date in calculate 2 years from that date.

Hope someone can help, I'm clearly lacking in code knowledge lol.

Thanks in advance

Alison

Comment: So far I have this which clearly isn't correct. =IF([HF & EM Completed]="","tbc",[HF & EM Completed]+730,([HF & EM Continuation Completed]="","tbc",[HF & EM Continuation Completed]+730))

Answer (score 0):

The key functions you need is `OR` , `AND` , and `ISBLANK()`

For a documented list of all Functions see:
https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List
Take your text to start with:

> if the course A completed is empty leave blank,

> if its got a date in calculate 2 years from that date,

> and if the course B completed column is empty leave blank

> or if it has a date in calculate 2 years from that date

Then step by step try to write it in SharePoint code, use a text editor Notepad will do,
and use muliple lines and indentations, SharePoint will ignore/replace them all on saving.

You can also use Excel and use Named Cells to subsititute the other SharePoint Column Names... copy/paste the Formula is all that is needed then.